# fixing a div on top after scroll - issue on ios mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to get the effect as shown in the example below: https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/

Basically, I want to fix a div on top after the page is scrolled to a certain amount. The div will be initially given `position: relative` and after scrolling the window to a certain amount the div will be fixed on top and will have the property as `position: fixed`.

This works fine on the web but on IOS devices the device gets fixed on top only after the scroll is complete.

Is there any possible solution for this? So that div will get the fixed property on scroll and not after the scroll is complete.

Comment: This is due to an optimisation approach that iOS devices follow where scroll event is not triggered continuously, but only when the scroll has completed scrolling. There are some plugins available to override this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? One such plugin that I know of is iScroll if that helps.

Comment: not yet, tried some other plugins, will try with iScroll if it works..thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This usually works for me even in iOS (post initial scroll from top). Here is a JSFiddle for demonstration:
https://jsfiddle.net/fcoxg2kL/

There isn't really a solution for exactly what the OP wants. This is a bug in how Apple utilizes `position: fixed`. My solution does work for iOS post 'initial' scroll from top, and works in all other non-Apple devices (android, etc). Developers should develop for the masses, not just for Apple. Which is also why my solution is a good approach in the right direction - it unfortunately does not solve the Apple issue for initial scroll for iOS.

Only Apple can fix this problem unfortunately.

What I've set up is pretty straight forward - adding a class at a distance from the top of the page greater than 200px. The class I added is `madesticky`. In the CSS I have this class switch the structure with `position: relative;` to `position: fixed;`.

I hope this suggestion will either suffice in your endeavor to find what works for you, or point you in the right direction.

CSS:

```
.stickynav {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    }
    .stickynav.madesticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 5;
        }

    .stickynav *::before,
    .stickynav *::after,
    .stickynav * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
        box-sizing:         border-box;
        }

    .stickynav_inner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1000px;
        }

    .navlist { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        .navlist ul { list-style-type: none; }
            .navlist li { display: block; float: left; }
                .navlist a {
                    padding: 10px 15px;
                    display: block;
                    color: #fff;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    .navlist a:hover {
                        background-color: #454545;
                        }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="height: 200px;"></div>

<div class="stickynav">
    <div class="stickynav_inner">
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

JQuery:

```
/**
 * Header Scroll with Add/Remove Class Function
 */
function headerScrollResize(){

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll < 200) {
        $(".stickynav").removeClass("madesticky");
    }

    if (scroll >= 200) {
        $(".stickynav").addClass("madesticky");
    }

}
$(window).on('load scroll', function(){
    headerScrollResize();
});
```

Comment: You sound unsure about it, so I thought I would test it out on an iPhone 6 emulator. Turns out it doesn't work unless the user stops scrolling (Releases their finger of the screen) exactly what OP wants to fix. check out your code in action [here](https://gyazo.com/16b78bc580ca81bf47fa99c8ac33874e)

Comment: There isn't really a solution for exactly what the OP wants. This is a bug in how Apple utilizes position: fixed. My solution does work for iOS post 'initial' scroll from top, and works in all other non-apply devices (android). Developers should develop for the masses, not just for Apple. Which is also why my solution is a good approach in the right direction - it just not solve the Apple issue. Only Apple can fix this problem.

Comment: I am not going to have a discussion how developers should be developing or whether your solution is a good approach or not. You admit your "solution" dos not solve the Apple issue when OP main problem is with ios devices, so could you enlighten me which purpose your code serves here? "Only apple can solve this issue" is definitely the easy way out here. If you truly believe that is the case, you were better off posting that as a comment rather than writing a 176 words answer with code that does absolutely nothing to help OPs __main__ problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113154/discussion-between-5parc-and-scriptsconnect).